# How can I schedule a background thread to play sounds in my app?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a process which should react on some events. So when `playFromList()` is called it plays some sound from soundpool. Then in a thread I set a flag and for 3,5 seconds it should not play any sounds.

What I got is: It plays sound and if than wait 3,5 seconds. If `playFromList()` is called 5 times in 3,5 seconds it still gets to `SoundManager.playSound(listNr)`, and still is done in 17,5 seconds. And its not exactly what I wanted. I wanted method `SoundManager.playSound(listNr)` called only once.

```
public class Settings{
    public static boolean flag = false;
}

 public class Main{
 public void playFromList(int listNr,int g){

        if(!Settings.flag){
            SoundManager.playSound(listNr);
            if(g ==0){
                mpVolume((float) 0.3);
                t5sec.run();
            }else{pauseMus();}      
        }           
    }

        private Handler vijfSeconden = new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                mpVolume((float)0.8);
            }
        };
        Thread t5sec = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                if(Settings.flag == false){
                    Settings.flag = true;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3500); 
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Settings.flag = false;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    vijfSeconden.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                    Settings.flag = false;
                }
            }
        };
 }
```

Comment: and more important (for me) why my code is not working in this way. What did i missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems with the code. Probably most important thing that is strange is 
t5sec.run(), in Java you you should use start method on the Thread object to start new Thread. As written it will execute in the calling thread.
Second problem is absolute lack of synchronization, one way to fix that, I guess, would be to use AtomicBoolean instead of boolean in Settings.flag

Another issue is that it is quite expensive to start new thread every time. It is a bit hard to tell from the description precisely what you want to do, but if my understanding is correct you should just do something like this:

```
if ( (System.currentTimeInMillis() - lastTimePlayed) < 3500) {
 playSound();
 lastTimePlayed = System.currentTimeInMillis();
}
```

that's it and no threads required. You might want to use AtomicInteger to hold lastTimePlayed value if you want your class to be thread safe.

Comment: Thanks hgrey somehow I didnot even think about `System.currentTimeInMillis()` to use. And about lack of sycronization  I thought if the variable is mutated only at one point its not needed.. but i think that I was wrong.
About expensive to start a new thread..? what do you mean by expensive? resources?

Comment: Each thread consumes memory to hold things like stack, for example. Also it takes time to create it and the more threads you have the more context switches you will have. For the time being try not to use threads if not absolutely required

Comment: Ok.. so I will try to use threads only if absolutely needed :)
One more question.. is it possible to call an activity every lets say 10 minuts not using threads? Asking it just to make sure because I have one more thread with time.

Comment: This is not possible, but good news is that it is relatively easy to do using java.util.Timer, which will use threads under the hood

Comment: @Roman take a look at [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to start your activity every 10 mins.